# Que nome damos a uma estratégia de retórica quando apontamos um erro em uma proposta nossa antes que alguém possa criticá-la?

Tags: figuras-de-linguagem

Por exemplo:  "Sabemos que para construir o novo aeroporto teremos que acabar com aquele sistema ecológico. É lamentável, mas nada se pode fazer a respeito.  Ou construimos um novo aeroporto ou nunca teremos acesso a aviões de grande porte.

Tal estratégia, em Inglês, é chamada de ["procatalepsis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procatalepsis).  Como diríamos isso em Português?

Comment: Eu vejo como um tipo de *atenuação*, não saberia dizer um termo mais preciso (porque "atenuação" é um tanto amplo).

Comment: @BrunoLopes  Na verdade é mais uma estratégia de retórica e não uma falácia.  Re-editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É chamado de "[prolepse](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/prolepse.html)":

> Figura pela qual se previnem objeções, fazendo-as antecipadamente a si mesmo e refutando-as logo depois.

Do latim e do grego *[prolepsis](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=prolepsis&searchmode=term)*, "ação de tomar de antemão", "antecipação".

Comment: I Googled for a translation but couldn't find anything. Thank you.